# How do I create a multi-dimensional index array?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 3d array where basically the content is identical to the indeces used to access it. So `m[2,5]` would result in `array([2, 5])`.
I couldn't find an obvious solution with the numpy functions `indices`, `ogrid`, `concatenate`, etc.

At the moment I'm using this, but was wondering whether there is a solution that makes better use of the API:

```
a, b = 3, 4
m = np.ones((a, b, 2))
for x in range(a):
    m[x,:, 1] = np.array(range(b))
for y in range(b):
    m[:,y,0] = np.array(range(a))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `np.mgrid`:

```
a, b = 3, 4
m = np.mgrid[:a,:b].transpose(1,2,0)

print(m[1,2])
# array([1, 2])
```